# How to decrease access time to WebMethod when Web Service is shutdown in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, webmethod, shutdown

My application is using Web Service methods. When the Web Service is shutdown, the app tries to get the WebMethod and is freezes my app for about 2 seconds and then it catches the exception.

My point is to decrease the access time to minimum to the WebMethod when Web Service shuts down.

Is there any way to achieve it? Maybe by timeout? Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Possibly.  2 seconds isn't much. How would you distinguish between _server down_ and a _latent network_?  Say when someone is downloading the latest exciting episode of _Game of Thrones_?

Comment: Good point, but my Web Service won't be working for many people. There will be few people accessing it at one moment.

Comment: There can be lots of reasons for delays. If a 2 second web service delay is freezing your app, the right thing to do is to move that activity into the background (using e.g. a `BackgroundWorker`) so that the app can stay responsive.

Comment: To be honest, nearly all of my Web Service methods are in BackgroundWorker and it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Then fix that problem. Don't try to work around the [fallacies of distributed computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacies_of_distributed_computing)